# Functional programing pipe/compose and map imbrication (refacto)

Tags: javascript, typescript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I'm a beginner in functional programming,
There is a better way to write this ? Because map imbrication  is not really readable :p
*TypeScript*

```js
type $parse = (text: string) => string[][][];
const parse: $parse = pipe(split("\n\n\n"), map(pipe(split("\n\n"), map(pipe(split("\n"), filter(isNotEmpty))))));
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think I have any particular suggestions, except for laying out the code in a more readable manner.  I didn't understand what it did until I reformatted it like this:

```js
const parse = pipe (
  split ("\n\n\n"), 
  map (pipe (
    split ("\n\n"), 
    map (pipe (
      split ("\n"), 
      filter (isNotEmpty)
    ))
  ))
);
```

And then the code seems reasonably clear.